# Подскажите новичку где искать параметры для set_preference() в Selenium.webdriver.Firefox()

Tags: python, веб-программирование, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Начал недавно осваивать Selenium. Узнал, как можно поменять `useragent` с помощью метода `set_preference()` и параметра `general.useragent.override`.

Только вот не могу найти инфу по другим заголовкам. Везде искал и никак не могу понять, как мне искать другие подобные параметры и изменять заголовки при необходимости.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, ни гугл, ни chatgpt толком объяснить не могут)

Comment: в файрфокс открыть `about:config`

Comment: Но я вводил туда к примеру general.useragent.override и там его нет, чекал и настройках профиля pref.js, там тоже такого нет. Параметры по другим заголовкам там могут быть?

Comment: в pref.js только измененные параметры. Значит только гуглить по нужной функции. Полный список (и то не список) можно найти только в исходном коде.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)